# Condensing this logic with linq

Tags: c#, linq

How can I convert the following logic to LINQ?

`Flaggedlist` is a type of `List<string>`. `request.flagged` is a numeric value in a request POCO.

```
if (request.Flagged == 1)
{
    if (!patient.UserFlaggedList.Contains(request.UserId))
    {
         flaggedList.Add(request.UserId);
    }
}
else if (request.Flagged == 0)
{
    string usrid = flaggedList.Where(a => a == request.UserId).FirstOrDefault<string>();
    flaggedList.Remove(usrid);
}
```

Comment: Why do you feel the need to condense this particular piece of code?

Comment: LINQ is for querying data structures.  Much of what you're doing isn't a query, such as making modifications to a list, and as such doesn't belong in a LINQ query.  You're *already* doing the querying portions of this code snippet using LINQ.

Comment: Sorry. Did not word this question correctly. I meant to utilize extension methods - like in LINQ - for brevity.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It can be boiled down to two simple IF statements and the 2nd part shortened further still:

```
if (request.Flagged == 1 && !patient.UserFlaggedList.Contains(request.UserId))
    flaggedList.Add(request.UserId);

if (request.Flagged == 0)            
    flaggedList.Remove(flaggedList.FirstOrDefault(a => a == request.UserId));
```

Comment: This is what I was thinking. Much like everyone has already said, not much to do to it. But I like the brevity of this code. Thanks all.

Answer (score 0):

This is pretty condensed and clear, not sure why you'd want to make it more condensed. 
If you really want to make it shorter, maybe you can do this:

```
if (request.Flagged == 1 && !patient.UserFlaggedList.Contains(request.UserId))
{
    flaggedList.Add(request.UserId);
}
else if (request.Flagged == 0)
{
    flaggedList.Remove(flaggedList.Where(a => a == request.UserId).FirstOrDefault<string>());
}
```